# Phpword and cicle for variabile in php

Tags: phpword

I have two cicle for php for my function, i need to write the docx template with the variabile that are in the cicle for..

```
<?php
echo '<table class="tavola-pitagora">';
$deb = array();
$TAN = 3;
$RATA = 250;
$durata = 60;
$b = ( 1 + ( $TAN / 1200 ) );
for ( $i = 0; $i <= $durata; $i++ ) {
    echo '<tr>';
    $i = $i + 6;
    $deb[ $i ] = ( ( $durata + 6 ) - $i );
    $deb[ $i ] = ( pow( $b, -$deb[ $i ] ) );
    $deb[ $i ] = ( ( 1 - $deb[ $i ] ) / ( $TAN / 1200 ) ) * $RATA;


}


for ( $y = 0; $y <= ( $durata + 6 ); $y++ ) {
    $y = $y + 6;
    echo '<td>' . number_format( $deb[ $y ], 2, ',', '.' ) . '</td>';
    echo "&nbsp" . "&nbsp" . "&nbsp" . "&nbsp" . "&nbsp" . "&nbsp" . "&nbsp" . "&nbsp";
    $pippo = $deb[ 6 ];
    //echo $pippo;
    //$pluto = $deb[$y];
    //echo $pluto."</br>";

    //echo $pippo;
    $pluto = $deb[ $y ];
    echo '<td>' . number_format( ( $pippo ) - ( $pluto ), 2, ',', '.' ) . "</br>" . '</td>';
    //echo number_format(($deb[6])-($deb[$y]),2, ',', '.');
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

I need to write the result of $pippo-$pluto in docx template word use PHPword how i can to do it?

Comment: This is my Phpword class:require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('contratto.docx');

$search_replace_array = array('pippo'=>$pippo, 'pluto'=>$pluto));

Comment: echo '<td>' . number_format( ( $pippo ) - ( $pluto), 2, ',', '.' ) . "</br>" . '</td>';
 //echo '<td>' . number_format(($pippo)-($deb[$y]), 2, ',', '.' ) . "</br>" . '</td>';
 
 $residuo = $pippo-$pluto;
 
 
 echo '</tr>';
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('contratto.docx');
$search_replace_array = array(
 'DEB'=>$residuo,
 'RESIDUO'=>$pluto,
 );

$templateProcessor->setValueAdvanced($search_replace_array);


$templateProcessor->saveAs("appo/contrattoprova.docx");

Comment: Now i have the same variabile in print....